# strcpy() skipping array elements

Tags: c

I am attempting to share lines that I have read in via a text file into shared memory so my client can access those strings. My program only prints the first and last strings, seemingly ignoring the second and third lines.

for example, abcd and mnop would be printed out like this:

```
abcdmnop
abcdmnop
abcdmnop
abcdmnop
```

if this was the .txt file:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

I believe this loop in the main program may be the

```
for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < i; j++) {
    strcpy((mem + k), words[j]);
    k = strlen(words[j]);
}
```

Here is my main program:

```
int main() {
    const key_t key = 56871;
    FILE *ptr_fp;
    char words[600][600];
    char *mem;
    int i = 0;  
    ptr_fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");  

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(float) * 8, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    } 

    if (ptr_fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(words[i], 600, ptr_fp )&& i < 600) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    mem = (char *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if (mem == (char *)-1) {
        perror("shmat error\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < i; j++) {
            strcpy((mem + k), words[j]);
            k = strlen(words[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my client program loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", mem);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(float)*8` for the size in the `shmget` call? That seems a bit odd. What does the size of `float` have to do with your text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
k = strlen(words[j]);
```

You need to *increase* `k` by the length of the string:

```
k += strlen(words[j]);
```

Or simply use [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) to concatenate the strings:

```
strcat(mem, words[j]);
```

Of course, this requires you to initialize `mem[0]` to the string terminator character `'\0'` first.

Comment: apologies, that is the wrong size in that segment. I was playing around with stuff and didn't change it back. Thankyou, i'm not sure why I didn't think about concatenating it